# NSData to unsigned char *

Tags: objective-c

I need to convert NSData to something like `unsigned char b[16]`. This is what I have so far.

```
NSData *c = [@"testingsomething" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
unsigned char *a = (unsigned char *)[c bytes];
NSLog(@"size of a is %ld", sizeof(a));
unsigned char b[16] = "testingsomething";
NSLog(@"size of b is %ld", sizeof(b));
```

The output I get is;

```
size of a is 4
size of b is 16
```

How can I do this? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first instance, `sizeof` is giving you the size of a pointer, because you are giving it an object that is a pointer type. In the second instance, it is giving you the size of an array because you are giving `sizeof` an object of *array* type. In C, pointers and arrays are often interchangeable but they are still considered distinct types and have distinct semantics.

If you want to copy bytes to your own buffer, use `NSData`'s [`getBytes:range:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-CIACCFDG) method. Or, if you are trying to get the byte representation of a string in a specific encoding, have a look at `NSString`'s [`getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW19) method.